# Lost $_SESSION when call file through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, session, php-8

I know there are many similar questions, but I have not found a solution for my problem.
I have the web on a server, where the session through the ajax calls work correctly.

I am currently changing servers, and updated the code to php8 (it came from 7.1).
In localhost the session also works correctly (with php8), but in the new server (Amazon Lightsail), when I call a file through ajax, it generates a new session id.
I have looked for settings in php.ini, but I see everything correct.

I think it will be something about the server configuration, I will still put some of the affected code

Simpy ajax call:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: '/destiny.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
               idU: idU
              },
    ...
```

Destiny.php:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){ 
    @session_start();
}

$lang = getlang($_SESSION['Id_User'], "ppp");
```

**EDIT:**

I edit a destiny file only with this (see results on coments):

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION); //NULL
echo "ss->".session_id(); //ss->
```

I can't start session on php file called by Ajax.

Comment: It may or may not be relevant in this case, but when debugging you definitely don't want the [error suppression `@` operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

Comment: To be honest the IF test is a waste of time also, as the session will either be created or reused by the call to `session_start()`

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` tell you about `session.save_path`

Comment: Is your new server behind an **Load Balancer**? If so, and there are **>1** backend server, check whether **sticky session** is enabled at **LB** or not? Also, check when user lands on the main page, what is the session id and on submitting the ajax, is the session id remains same or gets changes? _(Chrome Developer console -> Application -> Cookies)_

Comment: @RiggsFolly, save path is: "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php80" I don't change it.

Comment: @Haridarshan I don't have active the Load Balancer for now. And the PHPSESSID cookie, don't change in chrome console when execute though ajax.